# Big curly braces Inside the equation

Tags: amsmath

I am trying to print following following equation in latex

[image: output_error]

The code I have

```
\documentclass{article}   
\usepackage{amsmath, amsthm, amssymb}
\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
  P(Z_{n+1}=T|Z,Z_{1}\dots Z_{n}; \alpha) =
    \begin{cases}
       c(n) = \frac{\alpha}{n} & \text{for }1\le i<l\\
            \\
    \end{cases}
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

The code doesn't produce the required output.

Produced result.

[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX!! It is better to state clearly what is not working (this compiles fine for me, so I'm not sure what the problem is) and to post a full [minimal working example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228). A LaTeX  MWE should start with a `\documentclass` command, have a minimal preamble  and then `\begin{document}...\end{document}`. zthe code should compile and be as small as possible to demonstrate your problem. This makes it much easier for people to help you --- and much more likely that they will!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like the following? (Observe that `\mid` gives better spacing than `|` does.)

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}   
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
  \begin{equation}
   P(z_{n+1}=t \mid z_{1},\dots ,z_{n}; \alpha) = 
  \begin{cases}
     \frac{n_t}{n+\alpha} & \text{if table $t$ is occupied}\\
     \frac{\alpha}{n+\alpha} & \text{if table $t$ is empty}
  \end{cases}
  \end{equation}
\end{document}
```

Comment: where I need to add \mid

Comment: It gives me  unaligned result.

Comment: @karu - You write `\mid` instead of `|`. Please explain what you mean by "unaligned result". (Clearly, the standalone code shown above does *not* generate this message.)

Comment: Please see the figure.

Comment: @karu - Something seems to have gone badly wrong when you transfererred my code to your computer. For instance, my code contains lowercase-z letters, but the new screenshot you've posted contains uppercase-Z letters. Moreover, your code seems to have lost the `\frac` and `\text` instructions. Please show the actual code that gave rise to the new screenshot you've posted.

Comment: I have changed the code according to my needs but the \frac is not working now. I have included math packages it solved the problem.

Comment: @karu - Which math packages helped solve the `\frac`-related problem?

Comment: \usepackage{mathchars}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{amsmath}

Comment: @karu - `amsmath` is definitely a very useful package to load, for all kinds of math-related typesetting issues. `setspace` is also a useful package, but it's not particularly math-related. I'm afraid I've never heard of a package called `mathchars` before; moreover, it doesn't seem to be available for download from the CTAN. :-(

Comment: mathchars is a package created for the thesis